# Problem with Flow Language Support on VSCode and the autocomplete feature for react-native app

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, flowtype

I have initiated a react-native project and added flow language support extention in vscode to use it's features. As it is mentioned in [flow-for-vscode](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode), after installing the extension, I should be able to run flow commands, but the terminal doesn't recognize the flow word. Although flow works for type checking and shows the errors in a good way, it doesn't show the autocomplete for class or type properties and methods. How can I solve this issue? I'm using Windows and flow version 0.107.0 and vs-code version 1.40.1.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround. It seems flow.useLSP has some issues, so I disabled it and just installed flow using yarn (or npm). Everything working fine by now.